# Reload NLog config after invalid config

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I haven't found anything on the net - is it possible to reload the config of NLog after it stopped logging because of an invalid config and start logging again?

I have a long running application which does not like to be restarted, but I do have to change log levels and targets from time to time to debug / tell the customer what happens to a single record in the system.

Sometimes there is a mistake in the logging configuration, NLog stops logging after reloading it via `autoReload=true` and doesn't start again after I adjusted the configuration. Is there any way to tell NLog that it can read the config again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the config from the API if you like, `LogManager.Configuration.Reload()`.

> Sometimes there is a mistake in the logging configuration, NLog stops logging after reloading it via "autoReload=true"

This bug has been fixed in NLog 4.0. See [bug report](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/273) and [news post](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html).

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! looks like it is time to upgrade then.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you are changing the configuration manually and not by settings within your application?

In my current project we have settings within our application that will change the configuration of NLog during runtime, meaning that you don't have to stop then start on each change of the configuration. This means we can handle things like logging level or log file during the runtime without having to rely on a restart.

I'd say that it may be more useful for you to provide the user the ability to change these in the settings for ease of usability and it's much easier to explain how to change a setting than it is to explain how to change a file. This is all provided within the NLog API which is very usable. This is under the assumption that the user has access to change settings which I would assume they would if they have to change the configuration file manually just now.

Comment: The customer does not change the log level himself; we are responsible for maintaining the software and do change the configuration from time to time. We use the auto-reload property of NLog to let it reload the config file during runtime (!) after a change. So setting the configuration via the application is not feasible atm. There are also special cases when we need to investigate and cannot rely on a fixed set of config changes (the application is *really* huge, just setting the level of everything to trace will slow it down way too much).

Comment: @trevorcolby sorry it sounded like the customer had to change the configuration themselves from your question. Being honest it still sounds like you need a mechanism within your application that allows for changes to the logging, perhaps where each section of the application has it's own logging level that you filter before sending to NLog. But I expect that to be able to tell within your application that NLog is not logging and to effectively new up a new instance would not be difficult but would require your application to understand that the log file was not being written to.

Comment: @trevorcolby ... I don't know if I'd want to be doing this personally as it would require file checking to make sure that there were no writes being done. What happens if you set the LogManager.ThrowsExceptions to true, do you get an exception when your configuration is incorrect after changing it?